# JDBC: Can I detect if a query is running instead of being queued?

Tags: java, jdbc

When I do `statement.execute()`, is there a way to know if the statement is really being executed or being queued ? Alternatively, is there a way to do `statement.status()` and know if it's running/queued ?

That's to detect queries taking a long time and blocking other queries on the same connection.

Comment: The JDBC API cannot tell you anything like that.  Some vendor drivers may, but it seems like the sort of thing you should use your database's monitoring tools for.  What is the reason for sharing a connection among multiple threads in the first place anyway?

Comment: I can't really use database specific tools since I want to support many kind of dbs.
I do the queries on the same connection before the model right now is to have one connection per user (and many users). It could make more sense to share the same connection pool for everybody but limit the connections per user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I do statement.execute(), is there a way to know if the statement is really being executed or being queued?

Not in the JDBC API.

> Alternatively, is there a way to do statement.status() and know if it's running/queued ?

No.

> That's to detect queries taking a long time and blocking other queries on the same connection.

Classic XY problem. There shouldn't *be* any other concurrent queries on the same connection. JDBC connections aren't thread-safe. Every thread should have its own connection. If you use a thread pool, every *method* should have its own connection, just about.

Comment: Or I should just not launch a query until another is finished to keep it non-concurrent.

Comment: @Frenchguy Why not just create a new connection (create here I mean getting from datasource/pool) and do your query? Is there any reason you want to have serialized access to DB?

Comment: @FrenchGuy You should use a different connection per thread, as I have already stated. I don't know why you keep avoiding the issue.

Comment: Oh yeah, one of my constraints is to have only one connection available (like the `psql` command line in fact)